# What is taking up R's memory? Memory allocation errors when running R via a bash script

Tags: r, bash

I'm running my R programmes in batch mode using a bash script. After a month or so of smooth sailing (my total bash/batch lifespan, so forgive me if I get the terminology wrong), my R scripts suddenly won't run due to memory allocation problems, even when I set them up to run with an obscene amount of memory given the dataset size. As an extreme example, I have written an R script which loads in packages (that I want to use for my analysis scripts) and performs simple arithmetic (i.e. no data imported, to rule out the issue being data related):

```
# Turn scientific notation off
options(scipen=999)

# Memory
gc() 

# Install and load in a few packages
library(pryr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

# Memory - check what is being used
mem_used()

# Perform basic operations
2+2
log(10)

# Memory - check again after operations
mem_used()
```

When I run this on 3*16GB nodes, the script takes approx 15 minutes to process, and then my output file appears as below:

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.7 Gb
Execution halted
```

Running some diagnostics on this (qacct -j jobid maxvmem), I'm finding the job used 55.456GB of memory before failing.

When I run the scripts using R CMD BATCH --vanilla or R CMD BATCH --save --no-restore, it works. When I go back to running without (R CMD BATCH only), it stops again, reporting the same error.

This is just a test script, but the same problem occurs when submitting different scripts, even if the presentation of the memory error varies, e.g. instead of the 4.7Gb message I might get:

```
Execution halted
Warning message:
system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

The problem persists when using different versions of R, but runs fine when I use R interactively (qrsh session). In case it's useful, by bash scripts look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash --login

#$ -cwd  


#$ -l mem256 # Specify 16GB nodes

#$ -pe smp.pe 3 



module load apps/gcc/R/4.1.2

R CMD BATCH Test_NO_DATA.R Test_NO_DATA.R.o$JOB_ID
```

How can I understand or find out what is preventing R from running from a clean slate memory wise? Using --vanilla is fine, but it worries me that this doesn't really address the underlying issue as the problem comes back as soon as I remove those commands.

**EDIT: I can't mark a comment as an answer, but MrFlick's comment worked for me.**

Comment: Perhaps reading env data? what if you use --no-restore ?

Comment: What’s in your .Rprofile?

Comment: Is there a `.rdata` file in the working directory? It sounds like R is trying to restore a previous workspace which is disabled when using `--vanilla`. In the future it's better to use `Rscript` rather than `R CMD BATCH` because it has better defaults that would prevent the creation or loading of the workspace in the first place.

Comment: @user438383 I'm not super clued up on how an .Rprofile is created, but to my knowledge I don't have one (at least I didn't set one up, and I can't find anything in my program files)

Comment: @RicVillalba Using --no-restore allows my code to run. I'm just unsure why I need to use this, i.e. what is it that it's trying to restore?

Comment: @hhattiecc what's the output of ```cat ~/.Rprofile```

Comment: @MrFlick Ah eureka! There was an R script of about 7 GB in my working directory, so I'm assuming after that was loaded in it exceeded the memory (also would explain why it was running for ~15 mins before returning the memory error). Before I deleted that file, I used Rscript instead of R CMD BATCH and that allowed the code to run. Does R CMD BATCH automatically restore .Rdata files? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes. `R CMD BATCH` will load .Rdata files unless you also pass `--no-restore` or `--vanilla`

Comment: I strongly ecommend a different workflow of _freshly starting_ each invocation. I have written countless R applications and 'scripts' that way, and run several from `cron` on a regular basis, including CRANberries. And I even co-wrote (and still maintain) `littler` aka `r` for this, though you can of course use `Rscript`, and these days even `R` itself for this.

Comment: And yes, having a Yuge file `.Rdata` in your current working directory will eat the memory _and that is as expected and documented_ as R will by default read it.

Comment: @hhattiecc as comments says it's trying to restore the variables you use previously (r restores the working environment each time) even when you do not run anything. suspect that your nodes are not as big to allocate the saved environment.